# "SVD did not converge" while using statsmodel.timeseriesanalysis.MarkovRegression

Tags: time-series, markov-process, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a MarkovRegression model `sm.tsa.MarkovRegression(spread, k_regimes=2, switching_variance=True)` to a time series of price spread.

This is the error that I get: **raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge**.

I have checked the data for nans and removed them. The price series is on an intraday basis and has a length of 6729.

Any help on dealing with this error is much appreciated.

Comment: SVD convergence failure occurs primarily due to NaNs, maybe be some singular matrix or, in rare case, memory issues. Also, did you check what happens changing the number of regimes?

Comment: I tried adding regimes. It did give me a result at 4 but the output did not make any sense in terms of const and sigma values. I don't think my time-series will fit into this model. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Atreya. It seems a bit odd, but not implausible, to have a result with regime $4$ but as you said, this didn't reveal any meaningful result. Could you provide the data for us to crunch into?

Comment: BTW, what prompted you to use Markov Switching Models? Is (are) there any evidence (s) of discernible regime(s) shift? I would like to know the context.

Comment: The idea to use a switching model came from an observation that I made. I am trying to model the relationship between two international indices. The relationship tends to change during the course of the day as other markets open. I am looking to find ways to model the relationship. I am sharing a sample of the data that I am using: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SF3INBYUStLUfa2c1Jb9xrmMHkM8NxnzMh0ruEzMxz8/edit?usp=sharing)